# How to check the values of first array in second array and add the values associated with them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays with values. I am trying to get `desiredArray` which should check `firstArray` values in `secondArray` and if its a match, it should add the numbers of those value associated with them and push it to `desiredArray`. Could any one help?

```js
firstArray = ["Jack Sparrow", "Ryan Gosling", "Peter Parker", "Mark Waugh", "Steve Jobs"]

secondArray = ["Jack Sparrow :10", "Ryan Gosling :40", "Peter Parker :30", "Mark Warner: 40", "Shane Warne :30", "Steve Jobs : 20", "Tony Stark :90", "Adam Gilchrist: 45.5"]

desiredArray = [100] //final answer here

function getCount(firstArray, secondArray) {
  firstArray.forEach((e1) => secondArray.forEach((e2) => {
    if (e1 === e2.split(":")[0].trim()) {
      desiredArray.push(e1)
    }
  }));

  return desiredArray;
  console.log(desiredArray);
}
```

Comment: Please show the attempt you made to solve this yourself. Remember that we are happy to help you debug code, but we're not here to write code for you

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan mentioned, I 100% vouch with that. Try referring [`How do I ask a good question`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're unsure about how to ask a question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sure. This is what i was trying to do

function getCount(firstArray,secondArray) {
    firstArray.forEach((e1)=>secondArray.forEach((e2)=>
    {
        if(e1===e2.split(":")[0].trim()){
            desiredArray.push(e1)
        }
    }
));
return desiredArray;
console.log(desiredArray);
}

Comment: @Harry You can edit your post and put your code there :)

Comment: @Eddie: Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 `reduce`. The first `reduce` is to create a temporary object from `secondArray`. Use the name as the key and the number as the value. This will make it easier to check if the name exist. No need to loop thru the `secondArray` every loop of `firstArray`

The second `reduce` is to loop thru the `firstArray` and sum the values.

```js
var firstArray = ["Jack Sparrow", "Ryan Gosling", "Peter Parker", "Mark Waugh", "Steve Jobs"]

var secondArray = ["Jack Sparrow :10", "Ryan Gosling :40", "Peter Parker :30", "Mark Warner: 40", "Shane Warne :30", "Steve Jobs : 20", "Tony Stark :90", "Adam Gilchrist: 45.5"];

var tempObject = secondArray.reduce((c, v) => {
  let [k, o] = v.split(':');
  c[k.trim()] = +o;
  return c;
}, {});

var desiredArray = [firstArray.reduce((c, v) => c + (tempObject[v] || 0), 0)];

console.log(desiredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
firstArray=["Jack Sparrow", "Ryan Gosling", "Peter Parker", "Mark Waugh", "Steve Jobs"];

secondArray=["Jack Sparrow :10", "Ryan Gosling :40", "Peter Parker :30", "Mark Warner: 40", "Shane Warne :30", "Steve Jobs : 20", "Tony Stark :90", "Adam Gilchrist: 45.5"];

var result = firstArray.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  var str = secondArray.find((b)=>b.includes(curr));
  if(str){
    a += Number(str.split(":")[1]);
  }
  return a;
},0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    let count = 0;

    secondArray.forEach(item => {
        let data = item.split(":");
        let key = data[0];
        let value = data[1];
        if(key in firstArray){
            count += value;
        }
    })

   let desiredArray = [count];
```